# How to output a tabulation into a file

Tags: write

With the commands `\openout` and `\write` I output text into a file. How can i output a tab ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \newwrite\tempfile
  \immediate\openout\tempfile="filename.txt"
  \immediate\write\tempfile{I want a tab at the beginning of this line}
  \immediate\closeout\tempfile
\end{document}
```

**EDIT1**

Following egreg's solution, i use `` \catcode`\^^I=12 ``. This works if i use directly the code, but not if i enclose the code in a command :

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
      \newwrite\tempfile
      \immediate\openout\tempfile="filename.txt"
      \begingroup
        \catcode`\^^I=12 %
        \immediate\write\tempfile{^^II want a tab at the beginning of this line}
      \endgroup
      \immediate\closeout\tempfile
    
    \newcommand{\test}{
    \newwrite\tempfilee
    \begingroup\catcode`\^^I=12 %
    \immediate\openout\tempfilee="filename2.txt"
        \immediate\write\tempfilee{^^II want a tab at the beginning of this line}
    \endgroup
    }
      
    \test   
    coucou
\end{document}
```

**EDIT2** . Thanks again to egreg. The 2nd solution works, but not if i call `\test` from inside another command, which is what i need :

```
\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=\jobname.out

\def\test{\begingroup\catcode`\^^I=12 \testaux}
\def\testaux#1{\immediate\write\tempfile{#1}\endgroup}

\newcommand{\makeit}{
\test{^^I<-TAB again}
}

\test{        <-TAB} % WORKS
\test{^^I<-TAB} %WORkS
\makeit %DOES NOT WORK
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
```

**EDIT 3**. The second solution of egreg works ...  but not if it is inside a `AtEndDocument` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\AtEndDocument{\test{^^Ifin du document}
\immediate\closeout\tempfile }

\begin{document}
\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=output.txt
\catcode`\^^I=\active
\def^^I{}
\def\test#1{\begingroup
\edef^^I{\string^^I}\immediate\write\tempfile{#1}\endgroup}

\test{^^I<-coucou} %% WORKS
\def\foo{\test{^^I<-Jojo}}
\foo  %% WORKS
\end{document}
```

But the last sentence "fin du document" has no TAB.

Comment: I beleive it is the `^^I` character. Albeit I can give it as an answer I would like to be more generic in my answer, which I am not that good at yet. :)

Comment: i tested, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Somewhat related question (about printing special character) [terminal output - Is there a way to typeout to the console using ANSI colors? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168460/is-there-a-way-to-typeout-to-the-console-using-ansi-colors)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Writing a literal TAB character in a file is, unfortunately, dependent on the TeX distribution you have and how the formats were initialized.

With a TeX Live distribution, the formats for `pdftex`, `pdflatex` and `latex` are prepared feeding the option `-translate-file=cp227.tcx`, that makes the TAB character "printable".

Compiling the input

```
\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=\jobname.out
\begingroup
  \catcode`\^^I=12 %
  \immediate\write\tempfile{^^I<-TAB}
\endgroup
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
\csname @@end\endcsname\end % trick for stopping with Plain TeX and LaTeX
```

with `tex` and with `pdftex` (on a TeX Live distribution) will produce two different results (I report the "hex dump"):

1. `5e 5e 49 3c 2d 54 41 42 0a` (`tex`)
2. `09 3c 2d 54 41 42 0a` (`pdftex`)

Indeed `tex` is *not* set up with the TCX translation that makes the TAB character printable.

If one compiles the file with `luatex` or `lualatex` the result will be as in case 2. With `xetex` it's still different.

1. `5e 5e 49 3c 2d 54 41 42 0a` (`xetex`)
2. `09 3c 2d 54 41 42 0a` (`xetex -8bit`)

Thus the `^^I` is written in this form with `tex`, `xetex` or `xelatex`, while it is written as a literal TAB with `pdftex`, `pdflatex`, `luatex` or `lualatex`, but also with `xetex` and `xelatex` *provided* they are called with the `-8bit` option.

The moral of the story is: don't use TABs and don't try writing them in files, for the result won't be predictable across systems and machines.

---

How to define a command that writes a line to a file respecting the TAB characters (assuming `pdftex`)?

One has to remember that the category codes are fixed once a token list has been read in by TeX. So one has to use a different strategy:

```
\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=\jobname.out

\def\test{\begingroup\catcode`\^^I=12 \testaux}
\def\testaux#1{\immediate\write\tempfile{#1}\endgroup}

\test{        <-TAB}
\test{^^I<-TAB}

\immediate\closeout\tempfile

\csname @@end\endcsname\end
```

This will write in `\jobname.out` (again showing the hex dump)

```
09 3c 2d 54 41 42 0a 09 3c 2d 54 41 42 0a
```

so two literal TABS (the space in the first argument to `\test` is supposed to be a TAB, which on this system may be converted to spaces, unfortunately) are written.

---

If you need `\test` to work also in the argument to another command, then the trick above won't work: something like `\foo{x \test{^^I<-TAB}}`, where `\foo` takes one argument, would defeat the delayed grabbing of the argument done in `\testaux` rather than in `\test`: when TeX stores the argument to `\foo` it fixes the category codes.

However there's another problem: TeX normalizes `^^I` to a space token as soon as it reads it (when `^^I` has category code 10). So your problem is much more difficult to solve. If you don't need the TAB in your file other than for the purpose of writing it, you can do

```
\catcode`\^^I=\active
\def^^I{}

\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=\jobname.out

\def\test#1{\begingroup
  \edef^^I{\string^^I}\immediate\write\tempfile{#1}\endgroup}

\test{        <-TAB}
\test{^^I<-TAB}

\def\foo#1{#1\test{#1}}

\foo{^^I<-TAB}

\immediate\closeout\tempfile

\csname @@end\endcsname\end
```

This has the limitation that the TAB won't print anything and a sequence `<SPACE><TAB><SPACE>` will print *two* spaces.

Consider very well *not* to proceed along this path.

If the commands where `\test` is needed are limited in number, one might proceed as in the case above giving a correct definition. If you want to allow `\test` as the argument to *any* command, you're out of luck.

---

If all you need is to do a write `\AtEndDocument`, you can say

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^I=12
\gdef\EndTest{\test{^^I<-TAB}}
\endgroup
\AtEndDocument{\EndTest}
```

One could do without defining a new command:

```
\begingroup
\lccode`?=`\^^I
\lowercase{\endgroup\AtEndDocument{\test{?fin du document}}}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\tempfile}
```

You can use a different character than `?`, what's important is that it's a category 12 character.

Comment: well, i understand the potential problems, but I need it, and i will use it always with pdftex. A biggest problem for me is : when i put your code in a command `\test` and i call `\test`, then the TAB is replaced by an empty space in the output file. Why ?

Comment: You need to define `\test` in a context where `^^I` already has category code 12. Please, update your question.

Comment: i think a `#1` ist missing in the def of `\testaux`, isnt it ? or maybe, i just do not understand the code... :(

Comment: ok, i think i got it. Anyway, it works :) Great !

Comment: just to check wether i understood or not : if we put a `#1` in the definition of `ţextaux`, it does not work anymore, because somehow, the replacement text of #1 ist expanded too early. Is it correct ?

Comment: next problem : i call \test inside another command ... and there it dos not work. :(

Comment: @nicolasroy If I define `\test` with an argument, setting a different category code for `^^I` would be useless, as the character tokens in the argument have already been assigned their category code.

Comment: If `\test` is in a `\AtEndDocument` in a documentclass, then the TABs have no effect:( Why ?

Comment: @nicolasroy It's hard to tell without an example.

Comment: egreg : see my third edit

Comment: @egreg: Hi, maybe you can modify your example file whit real `TAB` s using the tip given by Ulrich Diez at (tex.stackexchange.com/a/508103/7832) that is somehow related. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

You may define a new macro `\mytab` providing the TAB character with category 12.

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^I=12
\gdef\mytab{^^I}
\endgroup
```

Then, use `\mytab` (with a space at end) instead of `^^I` or `<TAB>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% memoize TAB char
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^I=12
\gdef\mytab{^^I}
\endgroup
% open temp file
\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=\jobname.out
% macro to write to temp file
\def\writetotemp#1{\immediate\write\tempfile{#1}}

\AtEndDocument{\writetotemp{\mytab<-TABEND}}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\tempfile}
\begin{document}
\immediate\write\tempfile{\mytab <-TAB1}
\writetotemp{\mytab <-TAB2}
\end{document}
```

Here is the dump of `\jobname.out`:

```
0000000  \t   <   -   T   A   B   1  \n  \t   <   -   T   A   B   2  \n
           3c09    542d    4241    0a31    3c09    542d    4241    0a32
0000020  \t   <   -   T   A   B   E   N   D  \n
           3c09    542d    4241    4e45    0a44
0000032
```