# tabulation minted xelatex

Tags: xetex, minted, tabbing

When I use tabulation inside the `minted` environment in `pdflatex`, they show as normal (several spaces).

But when I use `xelatex`, they appear as `^^I`.

Example (before each letter a b c, there is space-tabulation-space) :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\begin{minted}{c}
    a    b   c  
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

In pdflatex I obtain :

[image: result from pdflatex]

Using xelatex, I obtain :

[image: result from xelatex]

I tried different things to obtain the same behavior for tabulation in xelatex, but did not succeed. How can I do to obtain correct tabulation in `minted` under xelatex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to put `xelatex` into 8bit mode, thereby preventing the escaping of the tab character into a control character.

Try:

```
xelatex -8bit -shell-escape file.tex
```

See G. Poore's comment for more details.

Comment: `minted` needs `xelatex` to write tabs to a temporary external file, but `xelatex` requires a special setting to write literal tabs: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58732/how-to-output-a-tabulation-into-a-file/58740#58740