# Is there a way to typeout to the console using ANSI colors?

Tags: color, terminal-output

I'm trying to colorize diagnostic outputs to the console in order to make my stuff more visible in the endless stream of messages that LaTeX spits out.

### Example

However, all of my efforts like, for example

```
\typeout{^^1b[38;05;54m Indigo!} % Text line contains an invalid character.
\typeout{\char"001B[38;05;54m Indigo!} % \char "001B[38;05;54m Indigo!
```

seem to get subverted by TeX either not expanding certain commands within `\typeout` or claiming that there were `illegal character`s.

### Question

Is there a trick that would make this work?

Comment: Side note, see also [compiling - Reducing the console output of LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/reducing-the-console-output-of-latex)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two issues:

- LaTeX has assigned catcode 15 for character `^^1b` (decimal 27). The use of `^^1b` triggers then the error message:

  ```
  ! Text line contains an invalid character.
  ```

  Thus the catcode for the character needs to be changed (see the example below).
- TeX usually prints control characters with the `^^`-notation. TeX compilers can have command line options to change this behavior:

  - TeX Live: `-8bit` or `-translate-file=natural`
  - MikTeX: `--tcx=natural`

The following example file defines `\CSI` as shortcut for `^^1b[`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \@makeother\^^1b
\@firstofone{\endgroup
  \newcommand*{\CSI}{^^1b[}%
}

\typeout{}
\typeout{\CSI38;05;54mIndigo! \CSI1mBold\CSI22m \CSI4mUnderlined\CSI0m}
\typeout{\CSI37m\CSI41m\CSI1mBold white on red\CSI0m}
\typeout{}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: just tried it, using `xelatex -8bit ...` and it did work! that's great! i had tried some catcode mangling, as that is an obvious bit, but had missed out on the `-8bit` switch. i'm also not bold enough a TeX writer to try and have a `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup` *overlap* with a pair of braces... oh me oh my, is that even *legal*?—i'll immortalize this piece of code in a new module for https://github.com/loveencounterflow/cxltx-styles!

Comment: @flow: `\@firstofone` just reads and outputs its argument unchanged. The idea is that the argument including `^^1b` is read with the catcode setting that is active in the group. Then the catcode of the character token `^^1b` will not change, after the group is closed by `\endgroup`.

Comment: this is truly ingenious. i'd never thought that this construct could be valid in any language. i mean, `<div>x<span>y</div>z</span>` isn't valid HTML and `d[ ( x ] + 4 )` isn't valid JavaScript / Python / whatever, and for good reasons. it's baffling to see how much TeX works on a, as it were, "eat one token, chomp one token" base, how those braces are really more like implementation details of each individual macro rather than imposed by a global syntax (eg `textpos`: in `\begin{textblock*}{10mm}[0,0.5](20mm,30mm)` all the different arguments have different parens).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in LuaLaTeX. (at least using Lua `print()` does work)

Answer (score 5):

one way i've found involves using `\write18`. i created a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo -e "\x1b$*\x1b[0m"
```

and then in my TeX i do

```
\immediate\write18{esc "[38;05;54mhelo Indigo"}
```

in other words, i 'outsourced' printing the problematic `\x1b` escape character. now i wonder whether there's a solution that does not include an external script.