# filecontents replaces tabs with spaces

Tags: filecontents

`filecontents` package replaces tabs with spaces. Is there any solution to preserve tabs in the generated file without changing the following code?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{textWithTabs.txt}
Aa    Bb    Cc
1     2     3
\end{filecontents*}
```

Generated file is:

```
Aa Bb Cc
1 2 3
```

Desired file is:

```
Aa    Bb    Cc
1     2     3
```

Comment: That's a good question. `texdoc filecontents` says nothing about that point.

Comment: `texdoc usrguide` documents the original `filecontents` environment, before the environment is patched by the `filecontents` package. Quoting the document: _Only normal ASCII text characters (7-bit visible text) should be included in a filecontents environment. Anything else, such as tab characters, form-feeds or 8-bit characters, should not be included in a filecontents environment._ There is more text about the conversion to spaces. The document does not suggest any solution around this limitation.

Comment: @mvkorpel: That is interesting information, but does the package circumvents this? I found also nothing about this, as Clément already stated. The package `filecontents` version claims about `verbatim` writing the content, in this case, the tab characters should be preserved.

Comment: Related (and showing why this is a problem): [How to output a tabulation into a file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58732/)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The results we are seeing suggest that the `filecontents` package does nothing about this particular limitation. One could also assume that the package documentation would advertise the ability to preserve tabs if such a feature was implemented. I don't understand what you mean by "`verbatim` writing the content".

Comment: @mvkorpel: Sorry about `verbatim writing`... I meant, as stated in `filecontents` package manual *filecontents works much like verbatim* ... I misinterpreted this, that *verbatim* is used.

Comment: The `filecontents` environment makes the tab active ``\catcode`\^^I\active`` and later defines it to insert a space AFAIK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `scontents` package it is possible to save the `TAB`s character in the `<output file>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scontents}
\usepackage{xcolor,fvextra} % only for example
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
% Write real tabs
\begin{scontents}[write-out=textWithTabs.txt]
	Aa	Bb	Cc
	1	2	3
\end{scontents}
Show correct TABs in \verb|textWithTabs.txt|.
\VerbatimInput[obeytabs, showtabs, tab=\rightarrowfill, tabcolor=red,showspaces, spacecolor=blue]{textWithTabs.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX and package filcontents define the filecontents environment with a TAB character active in order to change it into a space.
To disable this feature, you have just to destroy this processus for TAB character. Then you have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\chardef\other=12
\begingroup%
\catcode`\*=11 %
\catcode`\^^M\active%
\catcode`\^^L\active\let^^L\relax%
\catcode`\^^I\other%
\gdef\filec@ntents#1{%
  \openin\@inputcheck#1 %
  \ifeof\@inputcheck%
    \@latex@warning@no@line%
        {Writing file `\@currdir#1'}%
  \else %
    \@latex@warning@no@line%
        {Overwriting file `\@currdir#1'}%
  \fi %
  \closein\@inputcheck %
  \chardef\reserved@c15 %
  \ch@ck7\reserved@c\write%
  \immediate\openout\reserved@c#1\relax%
  \if@tempswa%
    \immediate\write\reserved@c{%
      \@percentchar\@percentchar\space%
          \expandafter\@gobble\string\LaTeX2e file `#1'^^J%
      \@percentchar\@percentchar\space  generated by the %
        `\@currenvir' \expandafter\@gobblefour\string\newenvironment^^J%
      \@percentchar\@percentchar\space from source `\jobname' on %
         \number\year/\two@digits\month/\two@digits\day.^^J%
      \@percentchar\@percentchar}%
  \fi%
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials%
  \count0=128\relax %
  \loop %
    \catcode\count0=11\relax %
    \advance\count0 by 1\relax %
    \ifnum\count0<256 %
  \repeat %
  \edef\E{\@backslashchar end\string{\@currenvir\string}}%
  \edef\reserved@b{%
    \def\noexpand\reserved@b%
         ####1\E####2\E####3\relax}%
  \reserved@b{%
    \ifx\relax##3\relax%
      \immediate\write\reserved@c{##1}%
    \else%
      \edef^^M{\noexpand\end{\@currenvir}}%
      \ifx\relax##1\relax%
      \else%
          \@latex@warning{Writing text `##1' before %
             \string\end{\@currenvir}\MessageBreak as last line of #1}%
        \immediate\write\reserved@c{##1}%
      \fi%
      \ifx\relax##2\relax%
      \else%
         \@latex@warning{%
           Ignoring text `##2' after \string\end{\@currenvir}}%
      \fi%
    \fi%
    ^^M}%
  \catcode`\^^L\active%
  \let\L\@undefined%
  \def^^L{\@ifundefined L^^J^^J^^J}%
  \catcode`\^^I\other%
  \catcode`\^^M\active%
  \edef^^M##1^^M{%
    \noexpand\reserved@b##1\E\E\relax}}%
\endgroup%
\def\fc@no@preamblecmds#1\do\filecontents#2\do\filec@ntents#3\relax{%
  \gdef\@preamblecmds{#1#3}}
\expandafter\fc@no@preamblecmds\@preamblecmds\relax
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{textWithTabs.txt}
  Aa    Bb  Cc
  1 2   3
\end{filecontents*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice work, I can't see which lines have been modified, can you explain the modifications made?

Comment: I have created the \other code (catcode 'other' is 12).

The catcode of character ^^I has became \other (twice).

I have removed the definition of ^^I since it was no more an active char (catcode 13).

That's all.

Comment: I do not have a problem with the principle, but with its practical implementation in 71 lines of code. Which lines (numbers) are modified?

Comment: line 3 is a created one. Lines 8 and 65 are changed. In original code there was some lines after line 65 which define ^^I. These lines are removed in my code.

Answer (score -2):

Works fine. works like verbatim.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{textWithTabs.txt}
Aa          Bb             Cc
1           2              3
\end{filecontents*}

\end{document}
```

I got

[image]

Comment: This does not work, after replacing the spaces with tabs, on a mac with current texlive.  Are you sure the tabs in the input file were not converted to spaces by the editor?